# Visual Studio Code not running Python

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I'm using the newest version of Visual Studio Code and Python 3.6 (64 bit) on Windows 10.

I have the "Python" extension installed (the one made by Microsoft).

Every time I try to run a simple program [e.g., print("Hello, World!")] it says that "The command "python" wasn't spelled correctly or couldn't be found"! [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.034 seconds

It's a very simple *[Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program)* program that doesn't really need much. *Why* is Visual Studio Code not letting me run a Python file?

This is where my Python executable is stored:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe
```

Comment: If you need more information or screenshots I'll be happy to provide you with them.

Comment: Have you tried editing your PATH to include python.exe?

Comment: It appears you have the Code Runner extension installed and that's what's not working, not the Python extension from Microsoft (the `[Done]` is a tell-tale sign).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe there is problem with your interpreter.

Try this: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> → *Python: Select Interpreter* → select your path (*C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe*)

> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Python from an executable file and not from the Windows Store, you can change your terminal setting from *internal* to *external* and make `cmd` as the default terminal in Visual Studio Code.

You can directly edit those setting from `settings.json`:

```
"terminal.explorerKind": "external",
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do the equivalent of blowing in the NES cartridge...

IN VSCode, next to the "Run" icon, there is a drop down arrow.  Hit the dropdown arrow and select "Run Python File"

After that, running the code (Clicking the arrow) worked as expected.

I could not find this anywhere online. I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've pasted a file path to the Python executable on your system. This is the path to the Python interpreter executable (python.exe) within the Microsoft Visual Studio directory.

If you're trying to run a Python script or execute Python commands, you can open a command prompt or terminal and use this path along with the script name or command. For example:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\python.exe your_script.py

Replace your_script.py with the actual name of your Python script.

Alternatively, you might want to consider adding Python to your system's PATH environment variable. This makes it easier to run Python from any command prompt or terminal without specifying the full path.

Answer (score 0):

On the bottom left of your screen, check if it is showing "Restricted Mode". If it is, exit the Restricted Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I've just solved it!

instead of opening your python file directly, open a folder that contains your python file. This way a workplace will be opened and Vscode will ask you if you trust this workplace. Once you choose that you do trust it, it will let you run and debug your python files in that folder.